# Exclude records in a recordset that have null

Tags: sql

I've developed a timekeeping app for my employees and am working on the reporting. I have the following table. The way the app works is at the start of the day it inserts the first start time. When they change their status it inserts the stop time for the previous status, and a new start time for the new status. At the end of their day they select a quit status that only puts in a stop time.

```
Table Hours
    ┌────┬───┬──────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
    │ id │emp│hDate     │start │ stop │hHours│
    ├────┼───┼──────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
    │ 100│ 20│10/21/2018│ 8:00 │ 16:00│ 8.0  │  
    │ 101│ 20│10/22/2018│ 8:00 │ 10:00│ 2.0  │
    │ 102│ 22│10/22/2018│ 8:00 │ 9:00 │ 1.0  │
    │ 103│ 20│10/22/2018│ 10:00│ 12:00│ 2.0  │
    │ 104│ 20│10/22/2018│ 12:00│ 13:00│ 1.0  │
    │ 105│ 22│10/22/2018│ 9:00 │ 12:00│ 3.0  │
    │ 106│ 22│10/22/2018│ 12:00│ null │ null │
    │ 107│ 20│10/22/2018│ 13:00│ null │ null │
    └────┴───┴──────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

The report I'm trying to create is to tally the hours worked for a given day(s). But I don't want to include a date that has any `NULL` values in the stop time.

```
SELECT hDate, SUM(hHours) as hHours 
FROM tbl_Hours WHERE empID=20 and (hDate>='2018-10-15' and hDate<='2018-10-28') 
GROUP BY hDate 
ORDER BY hDate
```

How can I accomplish that? I'm not sure where to go or even what to research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the same query where the hDates are only that of without null values in stop:

```
SELECT hDate, SUM(hHours) as hHours 
FROM tbl_Hours WHERE empID=20 and (hDate>='2018-10-15' and hDate<='2018-10-28') 
AND hDate NOT IN (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT hDate
  FROM
    tbl_Hours
  WHERE stop IS NULL;
)
GROUP BY hDate 
ORDER BY hDate
```

---

Same query with joins instead of inline tables:

```
SELECT hDate, SUM(hHours) as hHours 
FROM tbl_Hours
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT hDate
  FROM
    tbl_Hours
  WHERE stop IS NULL;
) AS except_hDates
USING (hDate)
WHERE empID=20 and (hDate>='2018-10-15' and hDate<='2018-10-28')
AND except_hDates.hDate IS NULL
GROUP BY hDate 
ORDER BY hDate
```

Answer (score 2):

use not exist

```
   select hDate,sum(hHours) as hHours
   from Hours t where not exists 
                 ( select 1 from Hours t1
                    where t1.hDate = t.hDate and t1.stop is null
                  )
    and  t.emp = 20 and (hDate>='2018-10-15' and hDate<='2018-10-28')
  group by hDate
```

[DEMO IN FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=743deea7375c3fd944636df0dfce72ec)

Answer (score 1):

What about eliminating those rows in your main query like below? :

```
SELECT hDate, SUM(hHours) as hHours 
FROM (select * from tbl_Hours where stop is not null) t WHERE empID=20 and (hDate>='2018-10-15' and hDate<='2018-10-28') 
GROUP BY hDate 
ORDER BY hDate
```

Comment: This wouldn't discard the dates that have `null` stop values in other rows for the same date.

Comment: I interpret that as the OP wants to discard a date if it has any null stop values be it in the same row or not.

Comment: I think it would discard all the rows where stop is null, and this is what is asked as I interpret.